# C++\CLI generic class with method returning indirection to the generic type parameter

Tags: c++-cli

I have a generic class written in C++\CLI, which contains a method returning an instance of the generic type parameter:

```c
generic<typename TWidget> public ref class Factory abstract
{
    public:
       virtual TWidget^ MakeWidget() abstract;
}
```

My generic type (`TWidget`) will be a reference type, and so I wish my method (`MakeWidget`) to return an indirection to the type.  Compilation fails with the error

> error C3229: 'TWidget ^' : indirections on a generic type parameter are not allowed

Surely this is not an unusual scenario; am I mis-understanding something? (entirely possible as I rarely use this language).

Any suggestions as to how I can appease the compiler and achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

Because your TWidget type is already a reference type, and in fact, the compiler will force you to make it so, you can simply define the return of MakeWidget as TWidget.